# rows in mysql explain less than real rows

Tags: mysql

**There is a index with column**, its name is `my_index`.

```
create index my_index
    on table(column );
```

Real rows:

```
select count(*) from table as b where b.column is not null;
= 31517
```

Row in explains:

```
select count(*) from table as b where b.column is not null;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | b |  | range | my_index | my_index | 99 |  | 24294 | 100 | Using where; Using index |

**I wonder why rows in explain (24294) is less than real rows (31517)**

### After ANALYZE TABLE

```sql
ANALYZE TABLE Table
explain select count(*) from table as b where b.column is not null;
```

| id | select_type | table | partitions | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | filtered | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | b |  | range | my_index | my_index | 99 |  | 16594 | 100 | Using where; Using index |

**24294 => 16594 !!!**

Comment: Shown rows amount in EXPLAIN is approximate. Renew table statistic for more precise value.

Comment: @Akina Sorry, I have edited the description .

Comment: Provide `my_index` definition.

Comment: @Akina I have updated the description. It’s a single index for `column`

Comment: Looks like the index is used not as an index but like a compact version of the table, and fullscan by this index is performed. Does this index is needed for this query only, or there is a lot of queries which selects by definite values list or range?